# i am using array all array is correct but one array have different to other

Tags: php

My OUTPUT IS

```
{
  "session": true,
  "status": true,
  "msg": "user data find successfully",
  "user_detail": [
    {
      "user_name": "asad ali",
      "user_profile_pic": "localhost/uploads/image/9152108abc",
      "follow": false
    },
    {
      "image_path": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/1787860Discover All In One.png",
        "localhost/uploads/image/7947861Discover All In One.png"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user_name": "asim kabeer",
      "user_profile_pic": "localhost/uploads/image/1952108xyz",
      "follow": false,
      "image_path": [
        "localhost/uploads/image/6547860Discover All In One.png",
        "localhost/uploads/image/2152108Mart Zone - All in one.png"
      ]
    },
```

My Code is

```
      while ($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $userid = $rowb['user_id'];
        $user_name = $rowb['fast_name']." ".$rowb['last_name'];
        $user_pic_path=$rowb['user_pic_path'];
        $user_follow=$rowb['follower_id'];
        $image_path=$rowb['image_path'];
        if($user_follow == $user_id)
        {
            $user_followi = TRUE;
        }
        elseif($user_follow !== $user_id)
        {
            $user_followi = FALSE;
        }
        if(!isset($result[$userid]))
        {
            $result[] = array('user_name'=>$user_name,'user_profile_pic'=>$user_pic_path,'follow'=>$user_followi);
        }
        $result[$userid]['image_path'][] = $image_path;
    }
    $response['session']=TRUE;
    $response['status']=TRUE;
    $response['msg']="user data find successfully";
    $response['user_detail']=$result;
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Issue is
    i want to remove gap between follow & image path in first user asad ali
if you see all image path with no gap but 1st user asad ali have 2 line gap between follow & image_path see my output

Comment: Array always when printed will come with indexes (either numeric or associative).So i am unable to understand your issue exactly. Please elaborate

Comment: i want not print the index value, only actual value

Comment: Please post your expected outcome that you want.(add in your question). Then only some-one can answer

Comment: You can't because array will always come with indexes (either numeric like 0,1,2.... or associative like `username`,'password'.....)

Comment: tell me if any other code php

Answer (score 0):

When you use $result[] = x; php add x to end of numeric index.
If you want initiate $result for user you must use:

```
if(!isset($result[$userid]))
{
    $result[$userid] = array('user_name'=>$user_name,'user_profile_pic'=>$user_pic_path,'follow'=>$user_followi, 'image_path'=>[]);
}    
$result[$userid]['image_path'][] = $image_path;
```

Comment: Your $userid is numeric so output of $result is 0,1. What is true output? make a sample output for help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using $user_id in your code which will definitely have any value. You are using that as a key in

$result[$userid]['image_path'][] = $image_path;

So you have to remove $user_id so avoid index.

You can use :

```
if(!isset($result[$userid]))
{
    $data = array('user_name'=>$user_name,'user_profile_pic'=>$user_pic_path,'follow'=>$user_followi);
    $result[] = $data;
    $image_path = array("localhost/uploads/image/1787860Discover All In One.png","localhost/uploads/image/7947861Discover All In One.png");
}  
$result[]['image_path'] = $image_path;
$result =  json_encode($result);
```

Comment: why you put manually image path in $image_path variable whether in database many image_path available so it is not correct

Comment: I just gave you an example that how you can have your desired result. Though I don't have your complete code, so you can give $image_path array values dynamically.

Comment: i am using dynamically with your code but desire result not get

Comment: while ($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $userid = $rowb['user_id'];
    $user_name = $rowb['fast_name']." ".$rowb['last_name'];
    $image_path=$rowb['image_path'];
    if(!isset($result[$userid]))
    {
     $result[] = array('user_name'=>$user_name,'user_profile_pic'=>$user_pic_path,'follow'=>$user_followi);
 }    
 
    $result[$userid]['image_path'][] = $image_path;

}
$response['session']=TRUE;
$response['status']=TRUE;
$response['msg']="user data find successfully";
$response['user_detail']=$result;
echo json_encode($response);
}

Comment: ok tell me one thing then i accept your answer i have 2 column name and image_path when user upload image data insert into name with user name and with image path.one user allow many image upload for example asad upload 2 image then 1st row asad=>image1, 2nd row asad=>image2,3rd row ali=>image1 .. i want to print this like as ouput,name print only 1 time and all image related with and next user name 1 time and all images print plz tell me

Comment: Yes please .. !

Comment: i have 2 column name and image_path when user upload image data insert into name with user name and with image path.one user allow many image upload for example asad upload 2 image then 1st row asad=>image1, 2nd row asad=>image2,3rd row ali=>image1 .. i want to print this like as ouput,name print only 1 time and all image related with and next user name 1 time and all images related same user print plz tell me php code only

Comment: You have avoid $user_id, as i creates index. Use:

while ($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()) {
 $userid = $rowb['user_id']; 
 $user_name = $rowb['fast_name']." ".$rowb['last_name']; 
 $image_path=$rowb['image_path']; 
 if(!isset($result[$userid])) { 
  $result[] = array('user_name'=>$user_name,'user_profile_pic'=>$user_pic_‌​path,'follow'=>$user‌​_followi); 
  } 
 $result['image_path'][] = $image_path; 
 } 
 $response['session']=TRUE; 
 $response['status']=TRUE; 
 $response['msg']="user data find successfully"; 
 $response['user_detail']=$result; 
 echo json_encode($response);

Comment: if i avoid $user_id then output is not my desire format.means like this user 1 image 1,user id 2 image 2,.... but i want only user id print 1 time and related image and then next user id and same procedure

Comment: Then you can use:

while ($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()) {
 $userid = $rowb['user_id']; 
 $user_name = $rowb['fast_name']." ".$rowb['last_name']; 
 $image_path=$rowb['image_path']; 
 if(!isset($result[$userid])) { 
  $result[$userid]['detail'] = array('user_name'=>$user_name,'user_profile_pic'=>$user_pic_‌​path,'follow'=>$user‌​_followi); 
  } 
 $result[$userid]['image_path'] = $image_path; 
 } 
 $response['session']=TRUE; 
 $response['status']=TRUE; 
 $response['msg']="user data find successfully"; 
 $response['user_detail']=$result; 
 echo json_encode($response);